# Why does the matplotlib histogram bar disappear with increasing bins range?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ones = [1 for _ in range(500)]

plt.hist(ones, bins=range(50), orientation='horizontal', density=True)
```

yields the following plot:

[image]

A higher bins range still makes the bar visible:

`plt.hist(ones, bins=range(900), orientation='horizontal', density=True)`
[image]

However, increasing the bins range even further lets the plot disappear:

`plt.hist(ones, bins=range(999), orientation='horizontal', density=True)`
[image]

Obviously the bin width becomes thinner with an increasing bins range.
How can I nevertheless make the plot visible for `bins=range(999)`?

Comment: If you increase the `dpi`, the line becomes visible again. You can add `plt.figure(dpi=250)` before call to `plt.hist`.

Comment: Thank @hilberts_drinking_problem, this solved it for me! If you formulate an answer Im happy to accept. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ylim

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ones = [1 for _ in range(500)]

plt.hist(ones, bins=range(1000), orientation='horizontal')
plt.ylim(-3,3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Limiting the y-axis to a certain area indeed is a quick fix. However @hilberts_drinking_problem makes all plots visible regardless of what area.